# How to get push notifications from a remote git repository in real time?

Tags: bash, cron, bitbucket, githooks

I have a remote repository (bitbucket), a server repository (linux) and many local repositories (developers).

I want the server to be notified if some developer changes a branch in the remote.

Until now i tried using a bash script declared in cron in the server but the minimal resolution is 1 minute, so to adapt it for real-time seems to be very tricky. However, my approach is this:

```
path=/some/dir/

# something new in remote
if git fetch origin && [ `git rev-list HEAD...origin/master --count` != 0 ]
then
    echo 'Remote repository has changed. Pull needed' &>>$path/git-backup.log
    echo $d >> $path/git-backup.log
    git merge origin/master &>>$path/git-backup.log
fi
```

Comment: Are you able to add a post-checkout hook to your bitbucket remote? https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout

Comment: You have a stray `&&` after the `rev-list` test. Also four-word `git fetch` is generally not very useful as it doesn't update any local references. If all you want to do is tell if the remote ref has changed then just `git fetch origin` and `git rev-list --count master..origin/master` should tell you. `git diff --exit-code master origin/master` should work too and can be used without the `[ ... ]` wrapping. You could also just always fetch and merge and log, no?

Comment: You are right goatshepard, the solution is git hooks (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/conceptual-overview). In bitbucket this could be controlled via "Webhooks" having admin permissions. In my case i am installing an app in the server side to listen to a specific port in order to be notified. I'll post the code when finished.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I solved it

**In bitbucket side**

All you need is to declare a Webhook pointing to the server.

[image]

**In the server side**

You need a mechanism listening some port all the time. This is the content of celery_listengit.py which is running all the time:

```
import subprocess
import threading
from tasks import git_pull
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def listen_git4pull():

    # Range of bitbucket IP Addresses that we know.
    trusted = ['131.103.20', '165.254.145', '04.192.143']

    incoming = '.'.join(str(request.remote_addr).split('.')[:-1])
    if incoming in trusted:
        git_pull.delay()
        # OK
        resp = Response(status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        # HTTP not authorized
        resp = Response(status=403, mimetype='application/json')

    return resp


class CeleryThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        error_message = ('Something went wrong when trying to '
                         'start celery. Make sure it is '
                         'accessible to this script')
        command = ['celery',
                   '-A',
                   'tasks',
                   'worker',
                   '--loglevel=info']
        try:
            _ = subprocess.check_output(command)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(error_message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery_thread = CeleryThread()
    celery_thread.start()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And this is the contents of tasks, where git_pull() function is declared. This have to be delayed because git.pull() could take a lot of time, so it must run after server responds with HTPP OK status:

```
from git import *
from celery.app.base import Celery


app = Celery('tasks',
             backend='amqp://guest@localhost//',
             broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',)

@app.task
def git_pull():
    repo = Repo('.')
    o = repo.remotes.origin
    o.fetch()
    o.pull()
```